# magnific popup does not show images in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup JQ library to show gallery in pop-up overlay.
This is the base code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ristna tuletorn. Маяк на острове, Эстония. - Gallery test</title>
<base href="http://ristnatuletorn.eu/" />
<link href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'image',
    items: [
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/11.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/2.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/1.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/3.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/4.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/5.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/6.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/7.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/8.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/9.jpg'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/10.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/12.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/13.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/14.JPG'},
    {src:'/assets/gallery/1/15.JPG'},
 ],             
                          gallery: {
                             enabled: true
                                    }
        });
    });

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/components/gallery/css/web.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

</body>
</html>
```

It does not show images in FF browsers (Windows and Ubuntu). In Chrome it works ok.
This is the link to the live page: http://ristnatuletorn.eu/index.php?id=8

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you remove the max-height CSS property from the `<img>`.

The set `max-height: 36px;` is just too small, if you go into the console and debug it see what happens ass you go up to say 100px.

You somehow set this specifically for FF, since in Chrome it's at 633px.

Cheers

Comment: Fonzy thank you for quick help! How it would be better to fix this issue? Because this value sets somwhere in Magnific code and I do not want to tweak a core of this library.

Comment: I don't have a working answer, but here are some things you could try: set the height with !important in css for the element and see if it override ( you could do it with css pretags to only make it happen in FF). You could also use JS/JQ to check if the height is too small and apply a custom height if your gallery is static. But TBH there should be a way to implement it, so that it works per default - I googled a bit and never came accross this problem! Lovly site btw! Cheers

Comment: Thanks again for your help and ideas! There is a callback function in the library. I can use it to fix height with JS. But at the official website everything is OK with FF. And that's surprise me. At the end I gave up and switched to another gallery plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is a bit late, but since the answer was never posted... Try declaring DOCTYPE. I had the same issue and this fixed it for me. It is likely that your official site has a DOCTYPE declared and your test code did not.

Comment: this really saved me!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't declare my doctype and couldn't figure out what's wrong because I moved from JSP to regular HTML and forgot to copy the doctype. You're a real life saver!

Answer (score -1):

I've tried something but is not responsive anymore. Just used fixed popup size.

Comment out the following @ Line 1210. 
`item.img.css('max-height', mfp.wH-decr);`

Hope this helps!

Cheers!